# Appropriate RegEx for A-Za-z0-9 apostrophe, space, and hyphen with range

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a string using a Regular Expression that can only contain A-Za-z0-9 the apostrophe, space, and hyphen with a range. I've tried doing this in the following method to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

This should validate O'Neil,von-studder, vons studder, and fail if the range is greater than 20 characters or contains characters other than A-Za-z0-9 the apostrophe, space, and hyphen.

```
public static bool ValidLdapSearchString(string input, int minLength, int maxLength)
{
    try
    {
        string stringValid = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 " + Regex.Escape("'-") + "]{" + minLength + "," + maxLength + "}";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(stringValid);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && regEx.IsMatch(input))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `$` or `\z` anchor at the end and there is no need escaping the symbols you escaped with `Regex.Escape`:

```
string stringValid = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]{" + minLength + "," + maxLength + "}$";
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9+%27-%5d%7b3%2c20%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=O%27Neil%0d%0avon-studder%0d%0avons+studder&o=m)

Note that you do not have to escape the hyphen because it is located at the end of the character class (right before the closing `]`). `'` is not a special character and does not have to be escaped.

If you need to make sure the string consists of just these symbols and has no trailing newline, use `\z` anchor instead of `$` (that matches either at the end of string or the end of string right before the last `\n` in the string).

Comment: Actually, the `'` is an apostrophe - did you call `'` a dash? Then `—–` should be removed.

Comment: I need the ' apostrophe and the dash -

Comment: Cool, that means the regex should be working. You can remove em-dash `—` or en-dash `–`.

Comment: I just got a bit stumped when I saw *dash, and hyphen*. So, you mean just a hyphen, right? Please adjust the question heading and contents.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you for your help. I am up and running now.

Comment: I also added some more explanations and adjusted the pattern.